# How to use FlashControl (MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, windows-8

I'm trying to use the **Windows 8 Camera API** to take picture with **flash** on a desktop app to use on a Windows 8.1 tablet.

I'm developing on **WPF** with **Windows 8.1**, **Visual Studio 2012** and the **Framework 4.5**.

By following this good [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-use-specific-winrt-api-from-desktop-apps-capturing-a-photo-using-your-webcam-into-a-wpf-app.aspx) I managed to take picture on my app.

Proof :

[image]

---

**BUT my flash led doesn't work when it's dark !** On the Camera W8 app, the flash led turns on automatically if needed.

I suppose that I should use the property [FlashControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.flashcontrol.aspx) of the [VideoDeviceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.aspx) but I can't access to it :

[image]

---

**Does somebody has an idea why I can't access to this property ?**

I have seen on msdn that the Minimum supported client is Windows 8.1. Should I use Visual Studio 2013 and Framework 4.5.1 to resolve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: My image comes out really dark. How did you adjust that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I figured out the answer.
Please check out this thread

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/afe878b7-e1e4-4859-9590-346f5d6866ab/flashcontrol-class-is-missing?forum=csharpgeneral